# Запуск внешних приложений с отображением QProgressBar

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, qprocess, qprogressbar

Уже долго мучаюсь, не могу найти решение...
Суть моего приложения, при выборе определенного `Checkbox` запускать выбранную программу, если выбираю несколько `Checkbox`, то запускается установка поочередно нескольких программ. Это у меня вроде бы получилось.

**Вопрос**: Как реализовать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки **`"Установить"`**, предварительно выбрав определенный `Checkbox`, открывалось новое дочернее окно с отслеживаемым процессом установки с помощью `QProgressBar` и отображением какая программа была установлена. Заранее спасибо!

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox, QWidget, QMainWindow, QApplication

import subprocess 
import threading
import time
import sys

class window_2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(window_2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.w2 = window_2()
        self.w2.resize(250, 300) #работает
        self.w2.setWindowTitle('Прогресс бар') 
        self.w2.progressBar = QProgressBar(self)  
        self.w2.progressBar.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 25) 
        self.w2.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.w2.progressBar.setMaximum(100) 
        self.w2.show() 

    
class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        
    def setupUi(self):
        window.resize(330, 259)
        quit = QAction("Quit", None )
        quit.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(window)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        #Кнопка Установить
        self.Btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Btn1.setCheckable(False)
        self.Btn1.toggle()
        self.Btn1.setEnabled(False)
        self.Btn1.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.Btn1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 160, 121, 41))
        self.Btn1.setObjectName("Btn1")
        #Кнопка 1
        self.checkBox1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 101, 31))
        self.checkBox1.setObjectName("checkBox1")
        self.checkBox1.stateChanged.connect( self.btnstate)
        #Кнопка 2
        self.checkBox2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 110, 101, 31))
        self.checkBox2.setObjectName("checkBox2")
        self.checkBox2.stateChanged.connect( self.btnstate)
        window.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(window)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        window.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(window)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(window)
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        close = QMessageBox()
        close.setText("Вы уверены что хотите выйти из программы?")
        close.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        close.setWindowTitle("Завершение программы")
        close = close.exec()

        if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
            self.setWindowTitle("Сборник программ")
   
    def retranslateUi(self, window):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        window.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Сборник программ офицера ОБИ"))
        self.Btn1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Установить"))
        self.checkBox1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Калькулятор"))
        self.checkBox2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paint"))
        
    def btnstate(self):
        if self.checkBox1.isChecked():
            self.Btn1.setEnabled(True)
            print("Выбран элемент для установки - Калькулятор")
        if self.checkBox2.isChecked():
            self.Btn1.setEnabled(True)
            print("Выбран элемент для установки - Paint")

    def start_in_thread(self, program):
        Popen(program)
        #time.sleep(10) # это для имитации долгой работы программы
        print(f'Запуск программы {program} завершен')

    def run(self, Btn):
        self.w2 = window_2()
        self.w2.setupUi()
        startlist = []
        if self.checkBox1.isChecked():
            startlist = subprocess.Popen("C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe".split(),
                             shell=False,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            self.stdout, self.stderr = startlist.communicate() #возврат
            
        if self.checkBox2.isChecked():
            startlist = subprocess.Popen("C:/Windows/system32/mspaint.exe".split(),
                             shell=False,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            self.stdout, self.stderr = startlist.communicate()

        

        for program in startlist:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.start_in_thread, args=[program])
            t.start() # запуск программы в отдельном потоке
            t.join() # ожидание окончания потока


main = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = window()
window.setupUi()
window.show()
sys.exit(main.exec_())
```

Comment: Там слот есть на прогрессбаре.

Answer (score 1):

1. Первое, что вы должны запомнить - **НИКОГДА НЕ изменяйте модуль созданный в QT Designer**.
   Создайте класс и наполните его тем что вы создали в QT Designer.
2. Вместо использования `subprocess.Popen()` лучше использовать `QProcess`,
   который является дружественным для графического интерфейса,
   поэтому нет необходимости использовать новый поток.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox, QWidget, QMainWindow, \
    QApplication, QProgressBar, QVBoxLayout, QLabel


class Window_2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):                          
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setWindowTitle('Прогресс бар') 
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar(self)  
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(100) 
        self.label = QLabel()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(330, 259) 

        quit = QAction("Quit", None )
        quit.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        #Кнопка Установить
        self.Btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Btn1.setCheckable(False)
        self.Btn1.toggle()
        self.Btn1.setEnabled(False)
        self.Btn1.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.Btn1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 160, 121, 41))
        self.Btn1.setObjectName("Btn1")
        #Кнопка 1
        self.checkBox1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 101, 31))
        self.checkBox1.setObjectName("checkBox1")
        self.checkBox1.stateChanged.connect( self.btnstate)
        #Кнопка 2
        self.checkBox2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.checkBox2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 110, 101, 31))
        self.checkBox2.setObjectName("checkBox2")
        self.checkBox2.stateChanged.connect( self.btnstate)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
   
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Сборник программ офицера ОБИ"))
        self.Btn1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Установить"))
        self.checkBox1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Калькулятор"))
        self.checkBox2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Paint"))
        
    
class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.w2 = Window_2()
        
        self._process_1 = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process_1.stateChanged.connect(self.new_State_1) 
        self._process_2 = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process_2.stateChanged.connect(self.new_State_2) 
        
        self.step = 0
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()                               
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_values)

    def update_values(self):
        self.step += 1
        self.w2.progressBar.setValue(self.step)
        if self.checkBox1.isChecked() and \
            not self.checkBox1.isChecked() and \
            self._process_1.isOpen():
            self.timer.stop()
        elif not self.checkBox1.isChecked() and \
            self.checkBox1.isChecked() and \
            self._process_2.isOpen():
            self.timer.stop()
        else: self.timer.stop()
        
    def new_State_1(self, newState):  
        if newState == 1:
            text = f"Процесс запускается, но программа 'calc.exe' еще не запущена.\n"
        elif newState == 2:
            text = f"Процесс запущен и программа 'calc.exe' готова к работе.\n"
        elif newState == 0:
            text = f"Процесс 'calc.exe' не запущен.\n"
        self.w2.label.setText(self.w2.label.text() + text)        

    def new_State_2(self, newState):  # notepad
        if newState == 1:
            text = f"Процесс запускается, но программа 'notepad.exe' еще не запущена.\n"
        elif newState == 2:
            text = f"Процесс запущен и программа 'notepad.exe' готова к работе.\n"
        elif newState == 0:
            text = f"Процесс 'notepad.exe' не запущен.\n"
        self.w2.label.setText(self.w2.label.text() + text) 
        
    def btnstate(self):
        if not self.checkBox1.isChecked() and not self.checkBox2.isChecked():    
            self.Btn1.setEnabled(False)
            return
        if self.checkBox1.isChecked():
            self.Btn1.setEnabled(True)
            print("Выбран элемент для установки - Калькулятор")
        if self.checkBox2.isChecked():
            self.Btn1.setEnabled(True)
            print("Выбран элемент для установки - Paint")

    def run(self):    
        self.w2.label.clear()
        self.step = 0
        self.w2.progressBar.setValue(self.step)        
        self.w2.show()
        
        self.timer.start(10)
        
        if self.checkBox1.isChecked():
            if self._process_1.state(): 
                self.w2.label.setText(self.w2.label.text() + "Процесс 'calc.exe' уже запущен\n")
            else:
                self._process_1.start('calc.exe') 
        if self.checkBox2.isChecked():
            if self._process_2.state():
                self.w2.label.setText(self.w2.label.text() + "Процесс 'notepad.exe' уже запущен\n")
            else:        
                self._process_2.start('notepad.exe')
            
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        close = QMessageBox()
        close.setText("Вы уверены что хотите выйти из программы?")
        close.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        close.setWindowTitle("Завершение программы")
        close = close.exec_()
        if close == QMessageBox.Yes:
            self._process_1.kill()
            self._process_2.kill()
            self.w2.close()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
            self.setWindowTitle("Сборник программ")
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(main.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за решение!

Comment: @e8s22  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour